# Is it possible to fetch multiple images through REST API?

Tags: wordpress-rest-api

I'm using API to fetch posts from wordpress. The thing is I wanted to get all images included in the post content too. I tried using 'media?' but it shows only 1 image file. Is there a way to fetch multiple images from wordpress posts?